# shinyTable does not work with partials

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have encountered a problem using shinyTable (great package by [Jeff Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133019/jeff-allen) using the amazing handsontable).

Strictly speaking is not a bug but it affects my app and the chance to use shinyTable.
Because of the size of my shiny app (over 45 tabs when finished) for manageability etc. it was suggested to me by Joe Cheng at RSTUDIO to use partials and containers.

Joe gave me some great code, that I have extended including a shinyTable example.
Please see: https://github.com/smartinsightsfromdata/partials

The problem is that by design the handsontable generated by the package is displayed the first time only that the tab is called.

Every other time that it is displayed after another tab / partial, the code thinks it has displayed it already and does nothing.
The problem is that the client does not have that code anymore (due to the change in "partial") and the only thing displayed​ is an empty table.

I would appreciate any indication on how to fix this problem in shiny, or how to change the package myself.

Comment: " 45 tabs when finished" This should prompt you re-look at your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to the issue:

There is another implementation of handsontable for shiny by AnalytixWare at https://github.com/AnalytixWare/ShinySky

The ShinySky implementation works well with partials.  The only drawback is that the cell style is not (yet) implemented.